# Pandas dataframe random number column

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe `df` and I want to add a new column `['RandomID']` which is essentially a randomised index. So a unique set of numbers with the lowest being one and the largest being the number of rows in the dataframe, but in a random order

I've found a few function which do something similar but not exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.arange()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html#numpy.arange/numpy.random.randint.html) to generate a list of unique numbers from 1 to the length of the dataframe, then use [`np.shuffle`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) to randomize the order, and finally assign to a column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.normal(size=100)})

idx = np.arange(1, len(df)+1, step=1)
np.random.shuffle(idx)
df['RandomID'] = idx

print(df)
print(f"RandomID ranges from {df['RandomID'].min()} to {df['RandomID'].max()}")
```

```
           x  RandomID
0   1.758036        35
1   0.318678        59
2   0.398764        99
3   1.723412        94
4   0.668306        40
..       ...       ...
95 -0.389478        28
96 -0.706779        89
97  1.865804        69
98 -0.899835        98
99 -0.311640        80

[100 rows x 2 columns]
RandomID ranges from 1 to 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
df["random"] = np.random.permutation(len(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can
create a list that goes from 1 to the length of your dataframe,
then shuffle it
and assign it to a new column.

Try this:

```py
import random
import pandas as pd

id_index = list(range(1, len(df["Repère fonctionnel"])))
random.shuffle(id_index)

df['RandomID'] = id_index
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import pandas as pd

column_data = [i for i in range(1, len(df) + 1)]
random.shuffle(column_data)
df['RandomID'] = column_data
```